# Coldfusion cfloop through checkboxes in a cfquery

Tags: mysql, coldfusion

I have had a good search through to see if there was something similar to what I am trying to do. Nothing specifically covers it though so without further ado.

I would like my cfloop to work through any of the checked boxes on a search page and display the appropriate results drawn from the database. This is what I have so far:

```
<cfquery name="joblibrary">
  SELECT * 
  FROM   tblJobLibraryRoles JOIN tblJobLibraryCategories 
               ON tblJobLibraryRoles.category = tblJobLibraryCategories.id
  <cfloop list="#form.cbGrade#" index="i">
      WHERE grade=<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#i#"/>
  </cfloop>
  ORDER BY category, grade, title, heraRef;
</cfquery>
```

Now it works all fine if only one checkbox is ticked, so I am basically asking can I get this type of CFLOOP to work in the way I've created it, or am I barking up the wrong tree?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need a loop.  Just use the sql keyword "in".

```
 where somefield in (
<cfqueryparam 
cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#form.checkboxfield#"
list="yes">
)
```

You just have to do something to contend with the situation where no boxes are checked.

Comment: Hi Dan, I'll give this a try and get back to you. As to if the checkboxes are checked, I have this particular part of the query wrapped in an if statement that checks if form element isDefined to cover that.

Comment: Further to my previous comment, I'd like to note that this worked fantastic and the if statement covers the unchecking issue well. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

`IN ()` is certainly the way to handle this (works with other sql statements as well), but there may be times where you want multiple WHERE conditions that are all entirely defined by variables.

Again, `IN ()` is the solution here, but I'll demonstrate with your query on how to do what you were originally wanting to do.

Simply add a `WHERE 0=0` (or 1=1 or anystring=anysamestring. You could even say `Where 'trickwhere'='trickwhere'` but there's no reason to get wordy with it) and loop over the rest using an AND instead.

```
<cfquery name="joblibrary">
  SELECT * from tblJobLibraryRoles JOIN tblJobLibraryCategories ON tblJobLibraryRoles.category=tblJobLibraryCategories.id
   WHERE 0=0
  <cfloop list="#form.cbGrade#" index="i">AND grade=<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#i#"/></cfloop>
  ORDER BY category, grade, title, heraRef;
</cfquery>
```

Comment: Thank you for the additional information. This may prove useful in future queries I build. Thanks!